# Need to Hide or Remove alternative x-axis values in d3 charts

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

In x-axis I need to show only values like - 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 and hide/remove other value labels(0.0, 1.0, 2.0 etc.,). I'm using D3 v3.

Chart Output should be like in the below image

[image: Chart Output should be like in the below image]

This is the code:

```js
var data = [{
    label: "Data Set 1",
    x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    label: "Data Set 2",
    x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
  }
];
var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
  .width(960)
  .height(500)
  .xlabel("X Axis")
  .ylabel("Y Axis");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .datum(data)
  .call(xy_chart);

function d3_xy_chart() {
  var width = 640,
    height = 480,
    xlabel = "X Axis Label",
    ylabel = "Y Axis Label";

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(datasets) {
      //
      // Create the plot. 
      //
      var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 80,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 50
        },
        innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
        innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, innerwidth])
        .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.min(d.x);
          }),
          d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d.x);
          })
        ]);

      var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([innerheight, 0])
        .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.min(d.y);
          }),
          d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d.y);
          })
        ]);

      var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
        .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

      var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient("bottom");

      var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_scale)
        .orient("left");

      var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-innerheight)
        .tickFormat("");

      var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_scale)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSize(-innerwidth)
        .tickFormat("");

      var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x_scale(d[0]);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y_scale(d[1]);
        });

      var svg = d3.select(this)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
        .call(x_grid);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y grid")
        .call(y_grid);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
        .call(x_axis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", "-.71em")
        .attr("x", innerwidth)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(xlabel);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(y_axis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(ylabel);

      var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
        .data(datasets.map(function(d) {
          return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
        }))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");

      data_lines.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return draw_line(d);
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(_, i) {
          return color_scale(i);
        });

      data_lines.append("text")
        .datum(function(d, i) {
          return {
            name: datasets[i].label,
            final: d[d.length - 1]
          };
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return ("translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
            y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")");
        })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", function(_, i) {
          return color_scale(i);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

    });
  }

  chart.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.xlabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xlabel;
    xlabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.ylabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return ylabel;
    ylabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path,
.grid line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

Comment: Play with d3 axis ticks option. https://observablehq.com/@d3/axis-ticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tickValues` and a remainder operator to check for integers:

```
.tickFormat(d => d%1 ? d : null);
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
var data = [{
    label: "Data Set 1",
    x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    label: "Data Set 2",
    x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
  }
];
var xy_chart = d3_xy_chart()
  .width(960)
  .height(500)
  .xlabel("X Axis")
  .ylabel("Y Axis");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .datum(data)
  .call(xy_chart);

function d3_xy_chart() {
  var width = 640,
    height = 480,
    xlabel = "X Axis Label",
    ylabel = "Y Axis Label";

  function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(datasets) {
      //
      // Create the plot. 
      //
      var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 80,
          bottom: 30,
          left: 50
        },
        innerwidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
        innerheight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, innerwidth])
        .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.min(d.x);
          }),
          d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d.x);
          })
        ]);

      var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([innerheight, 0])
        .domain([d3.min(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.min(d.y);
          }),
          d3.max(datasets, function(d) {
            return d3.max(d.y);
          })
        ]);

      var color_scale = d3.scale.category10()
        .domain(d3.range(datasets.length));

      var x_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d => d % 1 ? d : null);

      var y_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_scale)
        .orient("left");

      var x_grid = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x_scale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickSize(-innerheight)
        .tickFormat("");

      var y_grid = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y_scale)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSize(-innerwidth)
        .tickFormat("");

      var draw_line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) {
          return x_scale(d[0]);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y_scale(d[1]);
        });

      var svg = d3.select(this)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
        .call(x_grid);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y grid")
        .call(y_grid);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerheight + ")")
        .call(x_axis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", "-.71em")
        .attr("x", innerwidth)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(xlabel);

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(y_axis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(ylabel);

      var data_lines = svg.selectAll(".d3_xy_chart_line")
        .data(datasets.map(function(d) {
          return d3.zip(d.x, d.y);
        }))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "d3_xy_chart_line");

      data_lines.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
          return draw_line(d);
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(_, i) {
          return color_scale(i);
        });

      data_lines.append("text")
        .datum(function(d, i) {
          return {
            name: datasets[i].label,
            final: d[d.length - 1]
          };
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return ("translate(" + x_scale(d.final[0]) + "," +
            y_scale(d.final[1]) + ")");
        })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", function(_, i) {
          return color_scale(i);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.name;
        });

    });
  }

  chart.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.xlabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return xlabel;
    xlabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.ylabel = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return ylabel;
    ylabel = value;
    return chart;
  };

  return chart;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid path,
.grid line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```